# Rotating pictures

Tags: image, rotation, modula-2

I am currently programming a Tower Defence game for university and i stumbled upon a problem:
i want my towers to rotate towards the monster it is shooting at.
The towers are bitmaps and we are supposed to program in a language called Modula 2:
If you have heard of it any help is welcome to rotate bitmaps, if you havent it might still be helpful to know how i could start, how image rotation is done in general.

Thanks in advance,

Samuel

Comment: While this is obviously possible, it is far from trivial if you want it to look decent. Can you maybe get away with having several pre-rotated tower images and flip between those?

Comment: When manipulating images it is a good idea to start with a higher resolution than you need, perform the rotations, and then scale down the result to the correct size. If you try to rotate the scaled down image it will look terrible.

Comment: @ Per Larsen: I thought about that but for the smoothness of the game it would be preferable to have a proper rotation, i already thought it wouldn't be that easy to realize :P It would be much easier if i could already find a way to convert the bitmap into a 2D array of points, than a simple array rotation would do it...
@ Mark Byers: Yes and best would be anti-aliasing while scaling down, i'm gonna look for functions to achieve that